# Sinatra crashes when returning a hash from an eval statement

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eval

I have a hash of classes.

`$sites = Hash["cat", Cat.new, "dog", Dog.new]`

`Dog` has a function called `gmailOpen` that returns a hash.

```
class Dog
    def gmailOpen(foo)
        puts "it totally reaches this point"
        return Hash["from",foo]
    end
end
```

I call it in a weird way. Which works normally:
`result = eval("$sites['dog'].gmailOpen(1)")`

But when I call it as a result of a Sinatra get request, it breaks on the return statement with WebBrick telling me that you can't convert an array into a string: `Internal Server Error: can't convert Array into String`

```
class Controller < Sinatra::Base
  get '/hello/:id' do
    result = eval("$sites['dog'].gmailOpen(1)")
  end
end
```

It doesn't break if I return a string or an int, although it does break when I try to return an array.

In Sinatra, it also doesn't break if I'm not calling it through my hash of classes or if I call it without the `eval()`.

```
d = Dog.new
result = eval("d.gmailOpen(1)")
result = $sites['dog'].gmailOpen(1)
```

Why can't I return a hash?

Note: I could explain my use of `eval()` if desired. For now, please assume it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things that you can use as the [return value of a Sinatra route](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values). One of those is

> - An object that responds to `#each` and passes nothing but strings to the given block

Sinatra identifies such return types by [seeing if the object responds to `each`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1048), but doesn’t check the type of the object that is yielded.

You are trying to return a Hash object, and since a Hash responds to `each`, Sinatra assumes it is this type of object. However, `Hash#each` doesn’t yield Strings, but arrays (two element arrays of the key and value for each hash entry).

What happens next actually depends on what server you are running. With Thin, `to_s` is called on this array and returns the resulting string as the page body. With Webrick (the server that comes with Ruby and will be the default unless you have installed something else) the result is the error page you see with the message “can't convert Array into String” (with Ruby 2.0 the message is the similar “no implicit conversion of Array into String”).

The solution is to make sure you return a valid type from your routes. Note that if you need to you can set the response body with the [`body` method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Setting%20Body,%20Status%20Code%20and%20Headers), and then if necessary you can return `nil` to avoid replacing the value set with `body`.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out you can't have a Sinatra get request that doesn't return anything. So, when I change my method to:

```
class Controller < Sinatra::Base
  get '/hello/:id' do
    result = eval("$sites['dog'].gmailOpen(1)")
    "I have to return something."
  end
end
```

I no longer got the error. Thank you to everyone who took the time to look at this question, it encouraged me to think critically about my problem.